# Изменить шрифт условными комментариями

Tags: css

помогите пожалуйста на [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/weekend_projects/qie/) для ie уменьшить шрифт заголовка до 1px. в условных комментариях для него указана именно эта величина. но правило не срабатывает

пробовал режим

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сергей, доброго времени суток! Синтаксис условных комментариев такой:

```
<!--[if условие]> код <![endif]-->
```

Более подробно с примерами на [штмлбук](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii)

Comment: ну я в точности так и сделал. вот страничка
view-source:http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/weekend_projects/qie/

как видно, не работает такая конструкция

Comment: Работает. Вот ваш сайт в Chrome:

![alt text][1]

А вот в IE:

![alt text][2]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/9UmnGiL.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/N8OhIJN.png

Comment: странно. значит мой браузер глючит